# Gitlist can't find repositories directory

Tags: git, gitlist

I've installed the latest Gitlist version (0.5.0) on a CentOS 6.5 server. I've followed all the steps from install file but gitlist doesn't work.
I've searched in many blogs an sites to solve it, but Gitlist keep saying `Please, edit the config file and provide your repositories directory`
I've placed my repos under `/home/my_home/git_repos/`, I already tried to change permissions, add apache user to gituser group, and even move my repos to `/var/www/html/`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I got mine working by using

`chown -R apache:apache /git_repos/`

and

`chmod -R 755 /git_repos`

Give that a try.  also make sure that your config.ini is pointing to the correct location.